# Editing statistics for closed question

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, personal-statistics

I have edited a question before it was closed. Now my review statistics say I have edited 80 posts but my edit suggestions statistics show I have 81 edit suggestions approved. So, I ask if the difference between these two amounts is because of the question was closed.

Comment: I don't believe closed questions affect either, but deleted posts could lead to a difference in those numbers - I have no official reference for that though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Perhaps I should contact with administrators.